# Google Maps Geocoding APIs per seconds quota limit not matching documentation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering if someone had the same issue I have sometimes:

I am querying Google's servers and geocoding some places with a `setTimeout()` loop which resembles the following:

```
//...

var loop = function() {                
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Here I do the geocode request and create a CustomOverlay which I then show on the map.
                setTimeout(loop, 0); // Let the browser do some other work, e.g. rendering
            }, 125);
};
loop();

//...
```

Now, I have set the timeout to `125` milliseconds, which means that within 1 second at most 8 requests (`8 * 125 = 1000`) are made. But sometimes I get the Google's `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status code after a while when the script executes.

Now the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) says:

> Users of the standard API:
>
> - 2,500 free requests per day
> - **10 requests per second**

Why is `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` returned in my case? Is it because I also create a custom `Overlay`? I use the method `overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel()` for each result to convert the `lat` and `lng` returned from the Geocoder to pixels and to draw the overlay on the map. Maybe because of it?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Should consider storing the geocoded data...then you only need to geocode it once

Comment: You have a standard or premium account?

Comment: You are not allowed to permanently store geocoder results, only "cache" it for a period of time per the terms of use.

Comment: Guys, why the down vote? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Standard account.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes I am only caching them.

Comment: You should also consider not using the Webapi per the docs you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2500 requests per day works out to 34.56 sec/request over the long term.  The 10 request per second rate limit is only valid for short periods of time (approximately 10 requests).

(24 hrs/day * 60 min/hr * 60 sec/min)/2500 requests = 34.56 sec/request

The 2500 requests per day is the hard limit.  The 10 requests per second can change depending on server load and other things, including your recent history of requests.

Comment: Well, then I guess they should specify **approximately 10 request per second (may be less depending on the server load, etc.)**, anyway I didn't hit the 2500 requests limit. Anyway I am not blaming them, they have made a great work at the docs, they are really understandable.

Comment: Anyway, does the creation of the custom overlay adds an additional overhead of requests to the Google servers? For example, the `overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel()` method? Just to know...

Comment: The creation of the overlay has no impact on any quota.